# Composing Futures and Options

Tags: scala, functional-programming, for-comprehension

I have four types `A`,`B`, `C` and `D`, an initial value `x` of the type `Future[Option[A]]` and three functions: `f1: A => Option[B]` , `f2: B => Future[Option[C]]` and `f3: C => D`.

How can I write a `for` comprehension starting with `x` that results in a value of the type `Future[Option[D]]` that would be the "composition" of the three functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use monad transformers (from Scalaz) for this:

```
import scalaz.OptionT
import scalaz.std.option._
import scalaz.syntax.monad._
val result: Future[Option[D]] = (for {
  a <- OptionT(x)
  b <- OptionT(f1(a).point[Future])
  c <- OptionT(f2(b))
} yield f3(c)).run
```

You'll need a monad instance for `Future`; there's one in scalaz-contrib.

Comment: Thanks! I am sorry if the following looks like a stupid question: I managed to compile it using `Future{f1(a)}` instead of `f1(a).point[Future]` . Is there any difference? What Option's implementation should I use?

Comment: Scalaz includes type classes for `Option` but I'd omitted the import which I've fixed. You'd want to use `Future.successful(f1(a))` (this does the same thing as `f1(a).point[Future]`) rather than `Future{f1(a)}` because the former creates an already realised future whereas the latter will asynchronously run `f1(a)`, which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessarily the *best* solution, but it's what I've come up with.
I started by trying to find a common type to work with

```
type N[X, Y] = Option[X] => Future[Option[Y]]
```

...then converting `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` to that common type.

```
val f1: (A => Option[B]) = ???
val f1N: N[A, B] = {
  case None => Future.successful(None)
  case Some(a) => Future.successful(f1(a))
}

val f2: (B => Future[Option[C]]) = ???
val f2N: N[B, C] = {
  case None => Future.successful(None)
  case Some(b) => f2(b)
}

val f3: C => D = ???
val f3N: N[C, D] = {
  case None => Future.successful(None)
  case Some(c) => Future.successful(Some(f3(c)))
}
```

Now that I've created `f1N`, `f2N`, and `f3N`, I can use them in a nice-looking for-comprehension.

```
val y: Future[Option[D]] = for {
  aOpt <- x
  bOpt <- f1N(aOpt)
  cOpt <- f2N(bOpt)
  dOpt <- f3N(cOpt)
} yield dOpt
```